# Craft Cookies Plugin: Font Loading Detection

Tags: craft3, cookies

I'm trying to re-write my font loading detection using the [Craft Cookies Plugin](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-cookies). I'm unsure if what I have done is correct...

**Before**

```
<!--# if expr="$HTTP_COOKIE=/fonts\-loaded\=1/" -->
<html class="fonts-loaded" lang="{{ craft.app.language |slice(0,2) }}" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<!--# else -->
<html lang="{{ craft.app.language |slice(0,2) }}" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<!--# endif -->
```

**After**

```
{% if getCookie('fonts-loaded') %}
    {% do setCookie('fonts-loaded', fontLoad, now | date_modify("+1 hour").timestamp) %}
    <html class="fonts-loaded" lang="{{ craft.app.language |slice(0,2) }}" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
{% else %}
      <html lang="{{ craft.app.language |slice(0,2) }}" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure what you're accomplishing with this line:

```
    {% do setCookie('fonts-loaded', fontLoad, now | date_modify("+1 hour").timestamp) %}
```

I guess trying to give the cookie a longer duration if it was already set? Probably it's best to set the `fonts-loaded` cookie via JavaScript once FontFaceObserver tells us that the font as been loaded; there's probably no reason to do it here.

FWIW, we can start using the `font-display` property as a progressive enhancement now to want to eliminate FOUT on modern browsers. Older browsers will still work, but they'll get FOUT: https://caniuse.com/#search=font-display

Comment: Right - ok - are you saying FontFaceObserver isn't really required now due to font-display?

Comment: If you're ok with there being FOUT on older browsers that do not support the `font-display` property, then yes.

Comment: Ok that is clear - about 8% of our users are using an older browser past IE11...

Comment: Right so everything will still work for that 8% if you use `font-display` but there will be FOUT as the font loads. I think this is probably fine, but it's your call.